# Large cash requirement (2700 USD) for Russian citizens to fly to the US?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, money, scams, dme

My girlfriend is Russian. Last night we tried to fly her to the US on a valid tourist visa. She was stopped at DME and told she would be required to have $2700 USD to get back home immediately even though she had a return ticket. She said this was an "unwritten" rule because of the nonsense i keep seeing on CNN , Anybody else know anything? She is literally trapped and scared to death.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90153/does-a-verified-us-citizen-need-a-police-medical-report-to-return-from-ghana/90159#90159. Smells like a scam to me. Actually I am willing to bet a few dollars it is a scam either with her involvement as an accomplice or initiator, or her as an unwitting accomplice. Upon reconsideration I'm willing to say emphatically she's lying, sorry.

Comment: How much money did you send her already. How do you know she has a ticket and a visa? How do you know she is trapped and scared?

Comment: Have you ever met "your girlfriend" in real life?

Comment: @Mehrdad it would be extremely odd to call 'girlfriend' someone you haven't met, or?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo: Hence the question...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo It would be for me. But when these things come up, not only here, but also for exampe on [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18011/my-stepdaughter-wants-to-go-to-california-to-see-her-girlfriend), often this term seems to be used to refer to someone met over some internet service...

Comment: Likely scam perpetrated by your female friend. DME is a big airport and there are better targets than local women who don't have funds. The "They're holding me at the airport, send me money" scam is many decades old.

Comment: She's russian, she's at DME - ie, still in Russia, and they are charging her $2,700 to "get back home immediately" - ie, travel to Russia? While I hope this isn't a scam it has *all* the hallmarks of a scam.  There are people who will enter into months long relationships just to get to this point where they receive a $2,700 payday - on top of money already sent. I hope you haven't already sent her much money, but my guess is that even if you send this you'll find she has other problems that money will "fix", never meeting, and she won't give up until you stop sending money. Be aware.

Comment: My mother in law just arrived two days ago from Russia from DME. She and my Russian wife have never heard of such a requirement and they have flown here several times over the last few years. (My wife and I are currently living in US, so DME -> JFK)

Comment: Meh.  I say "Girlfriend" should be taken at face falue: "serious relationship, met many times, had plenty of opportunity to be merely carnal, past that, and now evaluating engagement." If OP wanted an answer for "person I've only ever met online and could be catfishing me for all I know", *then they should have asked **that** question.*   Garbage in, garbage out.  I would rather give tough love to morons than assume everyone is a moron.

Comment: @Harper: Part of the art of this kind of scam is manipulating the victim into believing it's a real relationship and using words like "girlfriend" despite having no actual relationship.

Answer (score 89):

I'm very sad to say that this has all the signs of a classic romance scam. How do you know this person? Have you ever met? We've seen several questions with the similar pattern. Here are some resources:

- [The US Embassy in Russia on Internet Dating Scams](https://ru.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/victims-of-crime/dating-scams/). One of their scenarios ("The individual I’m writing to says that s/he needs $1,000.00 to show for "pocket" money" or the airline won’t let him/her board the plane. Is this true?") matches your situation quite well.
- [Here's a story](http://www.meeting-russian-women.com/exit-fees-from-russia.html) from someone who was in the same situation.
- New York Times: [Russian Gal Seeking Comrade? No, It's an Internet Scam](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/11/03/world/europe/russian-gal-seeking-comrade-no-its-an-internet-scam.html?_r=0)
- [Scamwatch (Australian Government) on Dating and Romance scams](https://www.scamwatch.gov.au/types-of-scams/dating-romance)
- Krebs on Security: [Fraudsters Automate Russian Dating Scams](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0sTRyXqfd-4J:https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/01/fraudsters-automate-russian-dating-scams/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> “When you get down to the final stage, there has to be a crisis, some compelling reason why the target should you send the money,” said Holden, founder of Hold Security [full disclosure: Yours Truly is an uncompensated adviser to Holden’s company]. “Usually this is something like the girl is stranded at the airport or needs money to get a travel visa. There has to be some kind of distress situation for this person to be duped into wiring money, which can be anywhere between $200 and $2,000 on average.”

I highly recommend you not send any money or personal information to this person and that you report this to [the proper authorities](https://www.ic3.gov/default.aspx).

Comment: (+1) If this makes it a bit more convincing, I flew through Domodedovo airport quite a lot of times, and have never seen airline or passport control asking anyone to present any cash. Scam 100%.

Comment: "Whenever I get things like this, I mess with them. I AGREE to send them money via Western Union or Money Gram, and I send them a FAKE claim number. Hey, fair is fair... if they want to try to waste my time, it's only fair that I try to waste theirs!
" => definetly the best advice. +1

Comment: Your answer is probably correct but it in no way matches the situation described by the OP, namely that that girl is his girlfriend, which implies that they've already met, and more than one time. However, probably the question is wrongly worded and should be edited.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo People can call someone on the internet their "girlfriend" without meeting them.

Comment: @Yakk but then they live in the world of their fantasy and only from context you can find out what is the reality...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo How is that relevant?  All we have is the OP saying someone is their girlfriend.  This (the OP saying that it is their girlfriend) is consistent with someone who has never met the person in person, which makes this answer matching the OP's question.

Comment: @Yakk but if she were his girlfried, your answer would not match the case, because that spam targets people who date in internet and they scam out money before they could met in person. So yeah, it's quite relevant.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo - since the OP has now had at least 15 hours to correct the assumption of never having met this 'girlfriend', I think it's safe to continue to assume that this is a scam.

Comment: @brhans he didn't manage to trouble himself with correcting question as well...

Comment: @brhans OK I didn't thought that way. 'Girlfried' sounds better as 'someone pretending to be Russian girl that wants to date me when I cover all their expenses'.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo - with this sort of thing it's unlikely that the 'girlfriend' would actually want to date you, and the chances are fair that the person isn't even a girl ... This is just a scam to extort money from a 'rich westerner' with a whole lot of lies & deception.

Comment: @brhans exactly, my point, nobody will ever become your girlfriend, I was only confused by OPs choice of words.

Comment: It often happens where OPs, especially first-time-to-SE OPs *note that all of his rep is from **this** question*, are unable to log back in.  (most newuser SE queries are blind stabs in the dark, a "drive-by" if you will, with no expectaton of adding info, so they don't bother saving *yet another password*.)  When they do try to return, they inadvertently create a new account and are unable to comment due to rep.

Answer (score 17):

As a Russian citizen who's been to DME quite a few times and flew to and from the US I can say I've never seen, heard of or suspected any "illegal" briberies taking place at the airport.

There *is* a certain law that may prevent citizens from leaving the country if they have monetary debts to the state that exceed 10000 RUB, e.g. if they haven't paid taxes or fines in time. See [the original text](http://fzrf.su/zakon/ob-ispolnitelnom-proizvodstve-229-fz/st-67.php) or [a google translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffzrf.su%2Fzakon%2Fob-ispolnitelnom-proizvodstve-229-fz%2Fst-67.php&edit-text=) of the law. In such case the citizen is indeed required to pay the necessary amount to become legally "clean". However, the payment is made to the bank account of an official entity (whose bank account number is well known and can be verified via the Internet) and cannot be considered bribery. Moreover, you can check your girlfriend's legal status online yourself at any time [here](http://fssprus.ru/iss/ip/) and [here](https://money.yandex.ru/taxes/).

The Russian customs have also been known to do some borderline ridiculous things like singling out travelers and arbitrarily applying some obscure legal clauses that not many people are aware of, such as [calling your laptop or handheld console a cryptographic device without a permit](https://meduza.io/cards/tamozhnya-mozhet-priznat-noutbuk-ili-telefon-shifrovalnym-sredstvom-i-konfiskovat-kak-etogo-izbezhat), but all those checks were formally "legal" and the detainees were not extorted money from.

Good luck and please take it easy no matter how things go.