# Russian traveling to U.S. on a B1/B2 U.S. Visa

Tags: passports

I have a friend I meet over the internet. She claims the following below. Is she correct? I told her she is only staying a week!

"I can’t get a visa if I can’t prove my financial viability. This is a mandatory rule for all citizens traveling abroad as an independent tourist. I can not do anything. If I don’t have the full amount and until February 3 we can’t find the remaining 3155 $ USD."

Comment: Also see [Large cash requirement (2700 USD) for Russian citizens to fly to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94217/large-cash-requirement-2700-usd-for-russian-citizens-to-fly-to-the-us). Sounds like inflation might have bumped up the asking price.

Comment: This is a scam, pure and simple. Run away!

Comment: What she has told you is not correct, but she is not mistaken about the requirements.  She is *misrepresenting* the requirements.